# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'colorbox' Anonymous Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a light box to make a preview for some images so I used this light box in this demo :Here's [a link](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

so when I try to add it to my site this error is shown :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'colorbox' soap:281
(anonymous function) soap:281
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
D.extend.each
D.extend.ready
```

here is the jQuery code that i use :

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
        <script>

            var jQuery_min1 = $.noConflict(true);
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements

                $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});

            });
        </script>
```

and in my images gallery i put this :

```html
<ul id="carousel" class="elastislide-list" style="direction: ltr;">
      <?php 
           foreach ($content as $key => $value) {
                 echo '<li><a class="inline" href="#'.$value->p_id.'" ><img src="'. base_url().$value->p_image.'" alt="image01" /></a></li>';
           }                                 
      ?>                                
</ul>
foreach ($content as $key => $value) {
      echo'<div id = "'.$value->p_id.'" style = "display:none;" class="hidden"> 
            <div class="view-product-info">
                <div class="view-product-image">
                      <span class="field-content">
                         <img src="'.base_url().$value->p_image.'" alt="" title="" width="266" height="216" /> 
                      </span>
                 </div>
                 <div class="info" style="display: inline-block;">
                      <div class="views-product-title" >
                                                <br><br>
                           <span class="field-content"><a href="#1">'; if($language == 'ar') echo $value->p_name_ar; else echo $value->p_name; echo'</a></span>
                                                <br>
                       </div>

                  </div>
             </div>
                                </div>';
```

note : there are many another jQuery libraries I used ..

how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: `$(".inline")` is there actually an object instance here? i.e. `$(".inline")` is not null?

Comment: check in the console (firebug, chrome developer tools) that the colorbox.js file is loaded correctly because the error simply means that `$()` has not `colorbox` method, so it's not defined anywhere.

Comment: Why are you defining a nocoflict version of jQuery and then does not use it?

Maybe you meant:

     `var jQuery_min1 = $.noConflict(true);
     jQuery_min1(document).ready(function(){
       //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
       jQuery_min1(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
     });`

Comment: However, @JoeMinichino is right: the problem you should inspect is why colorbox.js does not get loaded...

Comment: I tried the comment of @AndreaSalicetti  i put this code :`var jQuery_min1 = $.noConflict(true); jQuery_min1(document).ready(function(){ //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements jQuery_min1(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"}); });` and the error didn't appear .. but no thing happen . i tried the Console of Chrome and all the files loaded correctly .

Comment: if in the console you type $('.inline') do you get any results? is the list of <li> populated correctly?

Comment: yes i tried to type $('.inline') in the console and i had a result

Comment: tried `jQuery_min1(".inline")` ?

Comment: Also return a result ..